# can you please explain "It does not meet our quality standards"?

Tags: discussion, site-faq, low-quality-posts

my friend tried to ask a question in english.stackexchange site  but it seems that there is a problem with his question, the message was : It does not meet our quality standards
BTW the question title was "what is the plural form of the word ( past )".

Comment: Try looking here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Asking a question into which time has been invested that adheres to the rules of English syntax will fix the problem. The filter checks for proper punctuation, capitalization, and clear formatting, along with a variety of other things. A clear question will be let through.
2. Ask your friend to look in a dictionary instead of posting simple questions that waste our time because the answers can be easily looked up. [For example, see Wiktionary.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/past#Noun)

Comment: thanks, I'll tell him "don't waste waiwai933's time by such questions" :)

Comment: While this is often true, it is not *always* true that a clear question will be let through.

Comment: In such cases it's perhaps better and easier to just post an answer which links to Wiktionary? See also http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7314/130551

Comment: @Nemo No, **absolutely not.** Link-only or quote-only answers are actively discouraged and may end up being removed.