# Question does not meet quality standards

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can you please explain “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/can-you-please-explain-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I tried to sent a question but I got this response:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - It does not meet our quality standards

Please let me know the reason why this happens.